# How to make Visual Studio 2010 highlight identical, selected words in editor ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I would like to enable (if it exists) an option in Visual Studio 2010 that would highlight the same identical words to the selected ones. 
There is a feature like this already implemented e.g. in Notepad++ it looks more or less like this :

[image]

Does anyone know if it exists in Visual Studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an extension on Microsofts Visual Studio Gallery named "[Highlight all occurrences of selected word](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb)" which promises what you're looking for.

Comment: Visual Assist X, although commercial, provides the same as one of its functions.

Answer (score 2):

Umm, this is a built in feature.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zainnab/how-to-use-reference-highlighting)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349251.aspx

Comment: Yeah this works but only for Basic and C#. ( I didn't mention that but I want it to work with C++ and the solution mentioned by Oliver works for that)

Answer (score 1):

People Looking for visual studio **2015**:

**https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulCzywczynski.Highlightalloccurrencesofselectedword**

It's a modified version of Nicholas Sha's plugin by Paul Czywczynski.
The syntax highlighting looks just like **notepad++**, but better.

It puts little markers on the line numbers of the occurances.

[**Screen Shot Here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XaU6.png)

Comment: Maybe the answer would be better here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494/visual-studio-identical-token-highlighting