# How to make Visual Studio 2010 Express highlight identical, selected words in editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Visual Studio 2010 highlight identical, selected words in editor ?](https://superuser.com/questions/386623/how-to-make-visual-studio-2010-highlight-identical-selected-words-in-editor)

How do I get the Express version to do what's explained here: [How to make Visual Studio 2010 highlight identical, selected words in editor ?](https://superuser.com/questions/386623/how-to-make-visual-studio-2010-highlight-identical-selected-words-in-editor)

Comment: Hi Phillip.  Welcome to SU.  Please don't duplicate questions.  I understand your different requirements, but since the other question isn't tied to a specific edition of 2010, it is the same question.  You should perhaps comment on that question requesting an Express equivalent. Or better, earn some Rep and [put up a bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) for better answers.

Comment: @techie007 The extension referred to in the given answer is not compatible with the Express version.  Nonetheless, as per your suggestion, I'll comment on the given answer in that question to request an Express-specific extension.